# Как вывести название всех функций и имена файлов со скриптами PHP, которые выполняются в ходе запроса к серверу?

Tags: php

Есть, например, к index.php. В этом файле происходят подключения других файлов с РНР-скриптами, а в них - вызовы разных функций. Как вывести на экран браузера информацию о том, какие именно функции и из каких файлов выполняются в ходе обработки запроса?

Comment: `debug_backtrace` вы про это говорите?

Comment: Я это  (debug_print_backtrace) пытался использовать, но она ничего не выводит вообще. Хотя, в index.php есть несколько require, которые используются, оттуда берутся данные, функции.

Comment: А как вы её вызывали?

Comment: debug_print_backtrace();

Comment: @Walfter, ему нужно не текущее состояние, а полная статистика

Comment: В самом начале файла после тега <?php

Comment: Да, полная статистика нужна.

Comment: Если полная статистика  то наверное какой-нибудь xhprof

Comment: А стандартными средствами РНР это нельзя сделать?

Comment: А чем вам xhprof не стандартное средство?

Comment: Он не выводит, вроде, порядка вызовов функций, имен файлов со скриптами.

Comment: [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/install)